# How do I restore the default Xubuntu boot screen?

Tags: xubuntu, plymouth

I experimented with some themes using 'plymouth'; now, I want to get the default boot screen back with its animation. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Current plymouth them**e is configured by a simple symlink in `/usr/share/plymouth/themes`.

Change the symlink `/usr/share/plymouth/themes` to point towards `/etc/alternatives/default.plymouth`

```
sudo rm /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth
sudo ln -s /etc/alternatives/default.plymouth /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth
```

Or run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
```

Assuming you still have that package installed. If not, just reinstall it with

```
sudo apt install plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
```

This is an answer for ubuntu. I don't know about xubuntu. It should be the same ?